# Open Cart - Filters Disappearing

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, opencart-3

An OpenCart (3.0.3.6) website was setup some years ago by developers that I am not able to get in touch with anymore... and for some reason **more than half of the filters have disappeared on a seemingly random principle**.

The website has around 10 filter categories most of which have a small number of entries in them, but **one filter category has around 1200 entries**.

The website administrator reports that **after adding a new entry to this category more than half of the other filters disappeared** (which I was able to confirm by looking at the database - only around 400 were left).

I am not an OpenCart expert... I looked at the code that corresponds to this action (saving the filters list - **admin/catalog/model/filter -> editFilter()** ) and compared it to a fresh OpenCart installation as I had doubts that the previous devs did something wrong - the code is the same, so we can exclude an issue with some custom code (I think...).

We were able to restore all of the filters as the website administrator had a backup, but now we are worried that adding even 1 filter to this category can break his website.

So my questions here are:

- Has anyone had this issue? Is this a known bug?
- Any idea of what the cause of it might be or how to resolve it?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Update:
When submitting the POST request to save the list of filters in the category I can see that only 333 items are in the "filters" array ... (out of around 1200).
So the saving after this actually works correct, but it "randomly" submits only 333  of the items in the filters list.
Each time the number (333) seems to be the same no matter the total amount of the existing or newly added filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue after analysing the POST request a bit more:

- Each filter has 3 parameters - id, name, sort order
- The POST request also contained the category name

The PHP version on the server was changed and (by default I guess) configured with **max_input_vars=1000**, which was the exact number of values contained in the POST request.

**Setting a higher value in php.ini** resolves the issue.